# Run code on publish/update of Wordpress page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-maps

I've built a website using Wordpress.

I have a template that has the following code, it is geocoding an address and saving the result into a new database.

I then have another template that reads all the lat/lng's from the new database and plots hundreds of markers on a Google map.

The problem is that the geocoding only happens when someone visits the page. This creates a couple of problems - 1) It geocodes EVERY time someone visits the page. 2) It ONLY geocodes when someone visits the page!

**Is there a way to run this code ONCE when Wordpress publishes/updates the page?**

This section grabs the company info from Wordpress and inserts it into the database:

```
    $company = get_field('company_name');
    $address = get_field('address');
    $city = get_field('city');
    $post_code = get_field('post_code');

    $sql = sprintf("select count('x') as cnt from markers where `name` = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($company));
    $row_dup = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql,$con));
    if ($row_dup['cnt'] == 0) {
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO markers (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`) VALUES ('".$company."', '".$address.", ".$city.", ".$post_code."', '0.0', '0.0', '')");
}
wp_reset_query();
```

Here's the full code:

```
  <?php
    require("database.php");
    // Opens a connection to a MySQL server
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);

    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("medicom_wp", $con);


        $company = get_field('company_name');
        $address = get_field('address');
        $city = get_field('city');
        $post_code = get_field('post_code');

        $sql = sprintf("select count('x') as cnt from markers where `name` = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($company));
        $row_dup = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($sql,$con));
        if ($row_dup['cnt'] == 0) {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO markers (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`) VALUES ('".$company."', '".$address.", ".$city.", ".$post_code."', '0.0', '0.0', '')");
    }
    wp_reset_query();


    define("MAPS_HOST", "maps.google.com");
    define("KEY", "");

    // Opens a connection to a MySQL server
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
    if (!$connection) {
      die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
    }

    // Set the active MySQL database
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
    if (!$db_selected) {
      die("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
    }

    // Select all the rows in the markers table
    $query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {
      die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    }

    // Initialize delay in geocode speed
    $delay = 0;
    $base_url = "http://" . MAPS_HOST . "/maps/geo?output=xml" . "&key=" . KEY;

    // Iterate through the rows, geocoding each address
    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $geocode_pending = true;

      while ($geocode_pending) {
        $address = $row["address"];
        $id = $row["id"];
        $request_url = $base_url . "&q=" . urlencode($address);
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url) or die("url not loading");

        $status = $xml->Response->Status->code;
        if (strcmp($status, "200") == 0) {
          // Successful geocode
          $geocode_pending = false;
          $coordinates = $xml->Response->Placemark->Point->coordinates;
          $coordinatesSplit = split(",", $coordinates);
          // Format: Longitude, Latitude, Altitude
          $lat = $coordinatesSplit[1];
          $lng = $coordinatesSplit[0];

          $query = sprintf("UPDATE markers " .
                 " SET lat = '%s', lng = '%s' " .
                 " WHERE id = '%s' LIMIT 1;",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($id));
          $update_result = mysql_query($query);
          if (!$update_result) {
            die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
          }
        } else if (strcmp($status, "620") == 0) {
          // sent geocodes too fast
          $delay += 1000;
        } else {
          // failure to geocode
          $geocode_pending = false;
          echo "Address " . $address . " failed to geocoded. ";
          echo "Received status " . $status . "
    \n";
        }
        usleep($delay);
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

In general:

In a plugin (or in the file functions.php located in your theme) you have the following code:

```
add_action('publish_post', function($post_id) {
  // Here you have some code that finds out the geocode data
  // then you attach it to this post as a meta value
  update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_geocode', $geo_data);
});
```

Then in your template file (single.php) you will have somehting like:

```
$geo_data = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_geocode', true);
if( $geo_data ) {
  get_template_part('geocode');
}
```

Or if you want to keep your template files clean you can add action "the_content"
in the file functions.php located in the theme directory (or in your plugin file)

```
add_action('the_content', function() {
  if( is_singular() ) {
    global $post;
    $geo_data = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_geocode', true);
    if( $geo_data ) {
      get_template_part('geocode');
    }   
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a google search like "wordpress add_action". Wordpress lets you "listen" to different events taking place within wordpress. In your case I think you can use the action named "update_post".

Comment: Ok thanks. So something like this `<?php add_action('publish_post', 'my_custom_function'); ?>` would go in my functions.php file to trigger the script I want?

Comment: Something like that. The second argument is the name of the function you will be invoked when the action "publish_post" is triggered.

Comment: Just to be clear, the only thing I want to happen admin area side is to click publish/update. Then on a template I want to check if the post was saved, if it was then I want to grab another template part using `get_template_part('geocode');`